# A question about fundamental matrix of a periodic ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$X(t)$ is a fundamental matrix for a periodic system ($x'=A(t)x$)   ,(A(t+T)=A(t))، there is a nonsingular and constant matrix $C$ such that $X(t+nT)=X(t)C^n $.
It's a problem in my ODE theory course and I tried to use floquet theorem but it did'nt helpful.

Comment: You do not need Floquet theorem at all. You only need to use uniqueness of solutions of the IVP. What $X(t+T)$ and $X(t)X(T)$ do solve?

Comment: What you mean about IVP?@PietroMajer

Comment: @PietroMajer can you write your answer with more detail?

Comment: Initial Value Problem. Do you agree that both $X(t+T)$ and $X(t)X(T) solve your linear system?

Comment: @PietroMajer yes I agree

Comment: Is it clear  now? Since both $X(t+T)$ and $X(t)X(T)$ solve the system, and since they coincide for $t=0$, they coincide for all $t$; then by induction it also follows $X(t+nT)=X(t)C^n$ for all $t$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $C:=X(T)$.

Comment: @PietroMajer how do you know $X(0) = Id$?

Comment: It may be assumed w.log. Otherwise if you prefer consider $X(t+T)$ and $X(t)C$ with $C:=X(0)^{-1}X(T)$ instead .